# inner join returning duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hello
i have the following query:

```
$k=mysql_query("SELECT cat.name_url, cat.id 
                    FROM category cat  
                    WHERE cat.name_url='".$_GET["category"]."' ");
 $kRow=mysql_fetch_assoc($k);


$j=mysql_query("SELECT s_cat.name, s_cat.name_url, s_cat.category_id 
                    FROM s_category s_cat 
                        INNER JOIN category cat 
                            ON s_cat.category_id=".$kRow["id"]." 
                    ORDER BY s_cat.name ASC ") or die (mysql_error());
```

i first fetch a  $_GET then use it in my second query but there i get duplicated rows when i fetch the arrays , if instead of using INNER JOIN i build my second query as:

```
$j=mysql_query("SELECT s_cat.name, s_cat.name_url, s_cat.category_id 
                    FROM s_category s_cat 
                    WHERE s_cat.category_id=".$kRow["id"]." 
                    ORDER BY s_cat.name ASC ") or die (mysql_error());
```

it will work and I wont get duplicates in the fetch row, waht is wrong with my INNER JOIN query?

cheers

Comment: Is it so hard to post code where you can read it all on the screen without having to use the horizonal scoll bar?

Comment: i dont know if it's hard , please teach me.

Answer (score 3):

syntax for inner join:

```
SELECT a.name, b.text 
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
WHERE a.name = 'something'
```

you're missing the "ON a.smth=b.smth" part

Comment: WHERE? INNER JOIN does require a WHERE?

Comment: unrelated. INNER JOIN is part of FROM clause, and it may or may not have a WHERE.

Comment: missing the ON? the ON is there, what do you mean?

Comment: in your query: ON a.id=123. Should be: ON a.id=b.a_id WHERE a.id=123

Comment: no way, this leads to an ultra verbose query here.(duplicated query command)

Comment: i just used implicit inner join query

Comment: and even if so: JOIN ON id WHERE smth_else=123

Answer (score 0):

use SELECT DISTINCT
that'll remove duplicates in your first query

Comment: "Fixing" problems with DISTINCT is rarely a good idea. Look at iluxas answer for the real problem.

Comment: iluxa's answer is the way you need to go if you don't want to use distinct.